# Why POSIX standardize semaphore as system call but leave mutex and condition variable to Pthread (user level)

Tags: pthreads, posix, mutex, semaphore, condition-variable

I came up with this strange question which haunted me. Why POSIX standardize support for semaphore as syscall but leave condition variable and mutex to pthread library?

What's the division of responsibility here? Why semaphore is not standardized in Pthread package? Why the syscall for synchronization that POSIX standardize is semaphore but not mutex, condition variable?

Don't know. Guess performance is the concern for not implementing mutex as syscall. (Atomic hardware instructions are unprivileged so implementing them at user level is possible. Even though Linux provide futex, it is actually trying to optimize spin lock into two phase lock, towards sleep lock). And the reason for semaphore is that semaphore can be manipulated by different process, compared to the fact that mutex can only be unlocked by the process that hold it? Semaphore's V operation allows process waiting for it unblocked. So semaphore is kept by kernel, and semaphore's id is like the file descriptor, a capability given out by kernel, which makes it a syscall but not purely user level package.

But what about condition variable? Any reason to specify it in Pthread but not syscall level? Because it is stateless and originates from monitor, which is purely stateless programming construct, so it can be implemented using mutex?

Thanks!

Comment: POSIX doesn't know about system calls, it only knows about _interfaces_, which may be implemented as fatter or thinner system calls, or completely in userland. I also don't think that POSIX mandates that the pthread implementation should be as a library. The entire premise of your question is completely wrong.

Comment: POSIX does not specify anything as a "system call".  If you really have to get yourself hung up on some artificial and effectively useless system call vs function differentiation, POSIX specifies **functions** for semaphore operations.  [For `sem_post()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_post.html): "The `sem_post()` **function** ..."  [`sem_init()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_init.html): "The `sem_init()` **function** ..."

Comment: @mosvy Thanks! Yes I misunderstood what POSIX specify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: semaphores and pthreads have separate histories.

Yes: semaphores can be used between processes where pthreads stuff is (generally) all within the current process, or between processes which share memory.

From a performance perspective: a quick poke (on my x86_64) tells me that `sem_wait()` and `sem_post()` use straightforward `lock cmpxchg` instructions, doing `syscall` only to suspend/wake-up a thread.  That is essentially the same as a `pthread_mutex_t` -- when the semaphore is used as a mutex.

Obviously a semaphore can do things that a mutex and a condition variable do not do, and you can use unnamed semaphores within a process -- `sem_init()` with `pshared=0`.

I guess the pthread developers decided that specifying a `pthread_sema_t` would be unnecessary duplication.  Sadly, it does leave room for doubt that the (more general) semaphore might have performance issues even when used only within a process :-(  Or, indeed, some doubt that semaphore and pthread stuff always play nicely together :-(

Comment: And in particular, semaphores (and shared-memory segments and message queues) have a much longer tradition in UNIX, being initially concerned with orchestrating the interactions of multiple cooperating *processes*, for which purpose they are still used.  That's what it means that they are grouped together as *inter-process communication* (IPC) tools.